# What recourse do you have for no explanation of dismissal?

Tags: hiring-process

I was given a work offer with a cable company twice; passed pre-employment checks(drug test and background check) and worked with a tech for training for two weeks but when it's time to issue my personal badge and tech number it's not approved and no explanation is given.

What is my recourse for any action I may take or how do I go about getting some answers?

Comment: Could you specify which country, and if you already had some sort of contract?

Comment: What do you mean you were given a work offer twice? Did you previously do the same training and have the same problem? Who's in charge of approval and did you ask why you were not approved?

Comment: 1)Nothing 2)Nothing 3)Nothing.

Comment: If you are in the US, you can be dismissed for no reason at all in most states. It is not in the company's best interest to give you a reason as that might mean that you could sue them for unfair dismissal if you could prove the reason was incorrect. Many HR departments now will not let the managers tell a reason to avoid drawn out legal battles. There is no recourse, and close to a 0% chance anyone there will give you a better explanation. Move on with your life.

Answer (score 5):

> What is my recourse for any action I may take or how do I go about
>   getting some answers?

You can ask HR / the person training you for details, but that that's about it.

If I understand your question clearly, you were in the training / probationary period, and during that time *in the US* the company can just let you go.

I do find it curious that you have been through you have been through the process twice without being offered the next step.  I think if I were you I would **skip the cable company** and move on to other opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's pretty unpleasant to do that without giving you any explanation but unpleasant or not they are within their rights to do so. You can *ask* them for an explanation but nothing compels them to give you one I'm afraid. I definitely would ask though.

Is this the same company both times?